# Cant create dropdown menu with CSS? li all on top of each other?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am following this tutorial here - http://html-tuts.com/jquery-dropdown-menu/ and have implemented their css to the best of my ability and yet I am left with all my drop down elements (li) on top of each other, not stacked vertically.

Here is my html:

[image]

CSS:

```
.dropDown {
     display: block;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;

 -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;

  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  color: white;
height: 30px;

  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropDown:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.dropDown a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.dropDown > li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;

}
```

I set the li to have a top of 100% however again, they are all in 1 place not stacked. How can I fix this?

I will eventually be implementing a slide down drop down. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or post your code to show what you've done so far? Can't seem to get a picture of your problem with analyzing your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply position absolute to your li, you're effectively setting the exact same position on all li elements (thus they remain on top of each other).

This is because position absolute elements hold no weight in the DOM, so it is possible to stack elements on top of each other with this positioning.

Try setting

```
position: relative;
```

on your li elements. This will give the elements weight and effectively stop them from being positioned on top of each other.